# If statement not presenting the else result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The else section of my code is not being displayed in my laravel blade. I need to get the else section of the statement to show. currently, that button is missing when the if statement is false.

```html
@auth
    @if(optional($quote->userLike))
        @foreach($quote->userLike as $like)
            @if($like->pivot->user_id == $id) //passing user  id from controller here
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}}" class="likequote">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control col-md-4" name="likequote" id="likequote" value='{{$quote->id}}'>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger shadow-lg " id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></button></i>
                </form>
            </li>
            @endif
        @endforeach 
    @else
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}}" class="likequote">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control col-md-4" name="likequote" id="likequote" value='{{$quote->id}}'>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow-lg " id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></button></i>
        </form>
    </li>
    @endif  
@endauth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first method

```html
@auth
    @forelse($quote->userLike as $like)
            @if($like->pivot->user_id == $id) //passing user  id from controller here
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}}" class="likequote">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control col-md-4" name="likequote" id="likequote" value='{{$quote->id}}'>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger shadow-lg " id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></button></i>
                </form>
            </li>
            @endif
    @empty
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}}" class="likequote">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control col-md-4" name="likequote" id="likequote" value='{{$quote->id}}'>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow-lg " id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></button></i>
        </form>
    </li>
    @endforelse
@endauth
```

- Second

```html
@auth
    @if(!empty($quote->userLike) && count($quote->userLike)>0)
        @foreach($quote->userLike as $like)
            @if($like->pivot->user_id == $id) //passing user  id from controller here
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}}" class="likequote">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control col-md-4" name="likequote" id="likequote" value='{{$quote->id}}'>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger shadow-lg " id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></button></i>
                </form>
            </li>
            @endif
        @endforeach 
    @else
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}}" class="likequote">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control col-md-4" name="likequote" id="likequote" value='{{$quote->id}}'>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow-lg " id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></button></i>
        </form>
    </li>
    @endif  
@endauth
```

Comment: Thanks @Akash The first example works if I remove the `@endforeach` in the middle. The second does not work. Button does not show.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can try this   

 @auth
     @isset($quote)
        @if($quote->userLike->count() > 0)
            @foreach($quote->userLike as $like)
                @if($like->pivot->user_id == $id) //passing user  id from controller here
                <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}}" class="likequote">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control col-md-4" name="likequote" id="likequote" value='{{$quote->id}}'>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger shadow-lg " id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></button></i>
                    </form>
                </li>
                @endif
            @endforeach 
        @else
        <li class="list-inline-item">
            <form  method="POST" action="{{route('likequote')}}" class="likequote">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control col-md-4" name="likequote" id="likequote" value='{{$quote->id}}'>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shadow-lg " id="savelike"><i class="fas fa-heart"></button></i>
            </form>
        </li>
        @endif  
     @endisset
    @endauth
```